# JavaScript alternative to Python requests.Session()

Tags: javascript, session

I have recently developed a Python API for a chatbot and made a demo using a quick python script:

```
s = request.Session()

user_response = None
while True:
    chat_response = s.get(url='http://localhost:5000/chat', json={'user_input': user_response}).json()
    if chat_response['is_end']:
        break
    if 'text' in response_json:
        print '\t' + response_json['text']
    user_response = raw_input()
```

When the chat route is called I set a unique session key

```
if 'session_id' not in session:
    session['session_id'] = chat_utils.id_generator()
```

This works great on the command line, the session id is used to keep track of the conversation on the server. However I am trying to implement this in a JavaScript front end. Is there an equivalent to the line

```
s = request.Session()
```

Currently I am unable to store session information so the initial question is repeated with a different generated key (see below).

[image]

This is generated using [BotUI](https://botui.org/)

The call to the API is made using the following code:

```
function chat(){
  botui.action.text({
    delay: 1000,
    action: {
      placeholder: 'User response here'
    }
  }).then(function (res) {
    sendxhr(res, textResponse)
  });
}

function sendxhr(user_input, formatter){

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/chat');
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("user_input", user_input);

  xhr.onload = function () {
    var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    console.log(res)
    formatter(res.text)
  }

  xhr.send();
}
```

The API call works but as there is no session each time the chat route starts a new session.

Comment: When you say 'a JavaScript front end', do you mean in a browser, or a stand alone JS process like node?

Comment: I have some simple html which runs my JS script.

Comment: You should probably re-ask this question as a new question, showing your non-working JS code instead of your working python code.

Comment: I had decided to ask the question this way around because the JS was not non-working. Just missing the session. I will add some relevant information to this post.

Comment: You can use the `sessionStorage` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @JosanIracheta - I have been trying to get my head around `sessionStorage` but I don't seem to be able to access it in the session on the server running my API.

Comment: You can only access it on the browser (front end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to serve the html. Rather than opening the html locally I added a route to serve static html.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The javascript is loaded in the html and everything works nicely.